# Leopard or Lion with Photoshop 11.0?

Tags: macos, itunes, snow-leopard, adobe-photoshop

I just downloaded OS7 to my iphone. To back it up on itunes it needs itunes 11.1. It wont download to my computer because I'm still running 10.5.8. If I upgrade to Snow Leopard or Lion I need to know that my old Photoshop 11.0/CS4 will still work.

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop CS4 [works with 10.4.11](http://helpx.adobe.com/en/x-productkb/policy-pricing/system-requirements-photoshop.html#main_Photoshop_CS4_system_requirements) and above. So yes it'll work with Snow Leopard or Lion.

There might be [some minor issues](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/known-issues-mac-os-10.html) on Lion. I don't know if the have been corrected since.

Comment: Your link seems to say 10.4.1 to 10.5.4 ...

Comment: Weird. You may have a look at http://blogs.adobe.com/jnack/files/Adobe-SnowLeopard_FAQ.pdf